# Angular 5 async pipe doesn't work with FirebaseDatabase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to experimenting with `Angular 5` and `Firebase` (Using `angularfire2`), and trying to observe the behavior of `async` pipe.

It was stated that whenever we attach `async` pipe to an `observable` it will automatically `unsubscribe` to the subscription whenever component got destroyed (i.e. `ngOnDestroy()`).

**However**, when I attach `async` pipe to **FirebaseDatabase**, see code below

```
// This is 'app.component.ts'
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  $mycourses;

  constructor(private firebaseDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.$mycourses = this.firebaseDB.list('courses').valueChanges();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('Component Destroyed');
  }
}
```

**while**

```
// This is 'app.component.html'
<h1>My Current Courses:</h1>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let course of $mycourses | async">
    <p class="course">{{ course.COURSE }}</p>
    <span class="course-code"> - {{ course.COURSE_CODE }}</span>
    <span class="au"> - {{ course.AU }}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<button (click)="ngOnDestroy()">Destroy Component</button>
```

**the expected behavior wasn't happening**, i.e. after clicking `Destroy Component` button, whenever i modify `list` and `object` on Firebase Console, my component still reflect the changes on database immediately, **while** it was supposed to not reflect the changes.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: how do you see the component when your component is destroyed and is not in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `ngOnDestroy` does not destroy the component.

https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy :

> Lifecycle hook that is called when a directive, pipe or service is destroyed.
>
> ngOnDestroy callback is typically used for any custom cleanup that
>   needs to occur when the instance is destroyed.

This means that you can do custom unsubscriptions in the ngOnDestroy function that would be called when the component is getting destroyed.

If you want to test component destruction, create a child component, and use templates :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="existingComponent">
 <child-component></child-component>
<ng-container>
<button (click)="existingComponent = !existingComponent">Create/Destroy</button>
```